# Solving $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^2}{x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

The following differential equation is given:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^2}{x}$$

Separating variables and integrating:
$$\int y^{-2} dy = \int x^{-1} dx$$
$$-y^{-1}=\ln|x|+c$$
$$y=\frac{1}{-c-\ln |x|}$$

But the solution is given as:
$$y=\frac{1}{-c-\ln x}$$

How can this omission of the modulus be explained?

Comment: The absolute value is sometimes skipped for convenience, if the domain is assumed to be $(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution given is for $x>0$ only.  There is also the solution $$y=\frac{1}{-c-\ln(-x)}$$ for $x<0$ only.  No solution may cross $x=0$.

Comment: In particular, thanks to the discontinuity, the "c" in each half can be specified independently.